# \autoref from hyperref with tex4ht

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, tex4ht

The following document when compiled with
    htlatex test-nameref.tex "html,4"
generates wrong targets (but correct displayed text) for the subsection and subsubsection references with the updated [nameref.4ht](http://tug.org/pipermail/tex4ht/attachments/20110511/04d3039b/attachment-0003.obj) provided by Radhakrishnan CV on [the tex4ht mailing list](http://tug.org/pipermail/tex4ht/2011q2/000306.html). The targets for the links are correct with

```
% nameref.4ht                           2010-09-04-21:02 %
% Copyright (C) 2005--2010       Eitan M. Gurari         %
```

distributed with MikTeX, but the displayed text is wrong.

Can anyone see what the problem is and provide a solution?

```
% test-nameref.tex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}
\label{chap:chapter}

\section{Section}
\label{sec:section}

\subsection{Subsection}
\label{subsec:section}

\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\label{subsubsec:section}

\begin{equation}
    a\label{eq:a}
\end{equation}


\begin{figure}
\caption{Figure.}
\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\autoref{eq:a}\\
\autoref{fig:test}\\
\autoref{chap:chapter}\\
\autoref{sec:section}\\
\autoref{subsec:section}\\
\autoref{subsubsec:section}\\

Equation~(\ref{eq:a})\\
Figure~\ref{fig:test}\\
Chapter~\ref{chap:chapter}\\
Section~\ref{sec:section}\\
Subsection~\ref{subsec:section}\\
Subsubsection~\ref{subsubsec:section}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been fixed now. Please grab the `nameref.4ht` from [here](http://download.river-valley.com/tex4ht/nameref.4ht). This will soon migrate to TeXLive.